# Run Java Program in Iseries(AS400)

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

Using Qshell,I have compiled Java Program that is saved in IFS Folder.After Compilation,Class file has been generated.But when i tried to run this class,it is not displaying any output.It simply gives $Prompt without any error.But when i checked the spool files,it is showing this:"**Unable to Complete Java Program because of reason 04 and Code 4 means:Unable to find method id required to run java program..**"

Ex. Simple Hello World Program :`System.out.prinln("Hello World");`
Compile:-cd /test(where test=directory where program is saved)
javac sample.java
Run:-java cp /test sample

Comment: You know the QSH command allow you to get a pseudo-Unix prompt?

Comment: (and for potential downvoters - the AS/400 platform is so different that just getting things to work is an issue in itself)

Comment: post full code. Why are you launching the program from outside test directory? Is `test` your package name?

Comment: Check your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks..The problem is main method defination..i was declaring it as "public static void main(String args)"..Now i have defined it as "Public static void main(String[] args)"..It is running fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The main method signature may not be valid.  The code should be placed inside a properly defined main method:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

To compile and execute from QSH:

```
$ javac HelloWorld.java
$ java HelloWorld
Hello World
```

See [Lesson: A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) for more information.